# Why is Firefox displaying my page differently?

Tags: css, firefox, layout

So the problem is: I have three column layout page. On the right side there is a commercial that I want to be able to turn off on a certain pages so the content expans and the page has two columns instead of three.

I found a solution using `display: table-cell`. That works in the biggest browsers but a strange problem occurs only in firefox. When I go to my page the commercial drops down below the content and the content expands. Then when I hit refresh the commercial pops up and everything seems fine.

Can you please help?

Here is the css:

```
#wrapper{width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;}

#left{float: left; width: 220px; margin: 6px 0 0 5px;}

#content_wrapper{float: left; width: 724px; margin: 6px 0 0 5px;}
    #content{min-height: 400px; min-width: 522px; max-width: 724px; border: solid 1px #ccc; padding: 12px; vertical-align:top; display: table-cell; }
    #right{width: 168px; padding: 0 6px 0 5px; display: table-cell;}
```

Comment: Your question is strange.  How can you say "that works in the biggest browsers" but then say "a strange problem occurs only in Firefox" -- since Firefox is the #2 browser these days, which "biggest browsers" does this work in?

Comment: That's because Firefox actually renders the page properly, unlike IE... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer [does not support table-cell](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#table) attibute, so if you use Internet explorer and, trying to check at Firefox, they will be difference. Probably firefox is actually working and but IE is not.

> No versions of Internet Explorer
>   (including IE8) support the property
>   values "inherit", "inline-table",
>   "run-in", "table", "table-caption",
>   "[table-cell](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp)", "table-column",
>   "table-column-group", "table-row", or
>   "table-row-group".

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast reply!

When I put in `display: table-cell` it fixes the layout for IE. I found out that IE does´t support the property but the thing is that IE is putting something in there instead of the table-cell property that fixes the layout. 

Maybe if I found out what that property is I could put in in my code. But I really have been trying.

Comment: IE doesn't support but putting something there mean, even you try to put `display: unknown-cell` it will act same thing? I think you should try to fix in different way though.

Comment: Ok. So inserting `display: unknown-cell` did the same thing for both browsers. The layout looks fine in IE but the commercial div is jumping up and down in firefox. So obviously I will have to find some other solution...

if you want to know the site is http://klifur.is

Comment: What is the element that you are trying to style? Elements get styled their default values when you feed them rubbish. For example, a `<div>` is a block element so if you do `div {display:utter-rubbish}` then the div will default to `display:block`. We need to know what the element is in order to know what the value is.

Comment: Problem solved! Got rid of the `display: table-cell` and put in `display: inline-block` instead. I also had to make some small changes to the template index file.